# Flutter: Value is empty

Tags: flutter, dart

A.file

```
void drawMarkers(){
    Marker marker = Marker();
    marker.getListFromFirestore(users);
    marker.getList(); <---- here2
  }

void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    drawMarkers();
    super.initState();
  }
```

B.file

```
class Marker{
  List<Model> list;

  void getListFromFirestore(List<dynamic> users) async {
    list = await NetworkRepository.fetchListsFromAllUsers(users); <---- here1
  }
       
  List<Model> getList(){
    return list;
  }
}
```

In my code, value of `list` is not empty (`here1`). But at `here2` the value is empty. what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `await` the call to `getListFromFirestore`, since it is `async`:

```dart
Future<void> drawMarkers() async{
    Marker marker = Marker();
    await marker.getListFromFirestore(users);
    marker.getList(); <---- here2
}
```